# Security Metadata in Android APK

Tags: android, google-play

As mentioned in this [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html)- Google to add new security metadata on top of each APK file starting from 2018 to verify the android application installed via Google Play Store.

My question: Is this metadata related with jarsigner & apksigner or Google to put this metadata when the application APK uploaded to Play Store in order to distribute? No detailed information found on the blog post or any other source. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

- `0x7109871a`: sign v2 (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/apksig/internal/apk/v2/V2SchemeSigner.java#73)
- `0xf05368c0`: sign v3 (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/apksig/internal/apk/v3/V3SchemeSigner.java#62)
- `0x2146444e`: google's security metadata, seems no drm data, i.e it's same for all users (of cousre, same versioned apk)
- `0x42726577`: padding (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/apksig/internal/apk/ApkSigningBlockUtils.java#72)

Comment: where did you find about securitymetadata hex value ? how do you know its same for all users, i can't see that hex value in sources mentioned

Comment: I have written a tool to check all the id and value. And I have ask several users to send me the apk, so I can check the value. It means it's same for the same versioned apk.

Comment: could you share that tool if possible ?

Comment: @user3826306 https://gist.github.com/liudongmiao/537d90fbc6485900f059dbab8542dfb5

Answer (score 3):

I have reverse-engineered the signature mechanism here: https://github.com/avast/apkverifier/blob/master/signingblock/frosting.go

It's called "frosting" internally and it is aimed mainly at P2P sharing of APKs. It is implemented in the Play Store APK, not the Android OS. Besides being signed by a key, play store also contains a "blacklist" of package names that can be marked as "not allowed" (currently empty).

The frosting is independent of the signing scheme - for example *com.facebook.orca* still uses scheme v1 but has frosting.

The frosting block is added by Play Store, so it proves that particular file was downloaded from Play Store, but not all APKs have it yet - APKs that were not updated recently are missing it. Also, sources like apkmirror.com might be getting APKs directly from developers, before they upload them to the Play store, so those will be missing frosting too.

Curiously, the frosting includes a metadata chunk encoded using protbuf. The structure is rather complex, it contains data like signing timestamp, versionCode, minSdkVersion and many more.

The [Google Photos APK](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/photos/photos-3-26-0-207647160-release/google-photos-3-26-0-207647160-4-android-apk-download/) has metadata that contain string `com.google.android.apps.photos.PIXEL_2018_PRELOAD`. The string seems to suggest that the APK was part of factory image, but the APK from my own phone (which is not a pixel) also has this string.

APKs inside Pixel 2 (XL) 9.0 factory images do not have frosting.

Comment: I suspect there's also some anti-piracy account tracking that they're either doing or in certain cases doing.

Comment: Uh, any reason for that? I have seen some samples[1] where only the frosting was different, but they each had different "version" set in the protobuf info and it was only two samples, definitely nothing suggesting that they are tied to some account. Frosting is not supposed to be DRM, it would not be very effective.


[1]: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/0262465bef52d854538803ea5a6908ce9b5ecd94e7eb14ee85e54c2c4318725b/detection vs https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/162c8bda7882a12c7ef0d33351b104310588dbfdb5f269c5a6d44a162cd14ed6/detection

Answer (score 2):

Neither `jarsigner` nor `apksigner` will be adding any such metadata. It appears that it is Google Play that will be adding this metadata, thus "stamping" APKs as "officially distributed by Google Play" (to quote the blog post). This stamping will have to occur at APK upload time or later, when the APK is distributed to installed base / users.

Answer (score 1):

In your linked blog post you should read this:

> We'll adjust Play's maximum APK size to take into account the small metadata addition, which is inserted into the [APK Signing Block](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2) and does not alter the functionality of your app.

So when you sign your apk before upload it to the store Google put this metadata into the APK Signing block. You don't have to worry about it, the signing process does it automatically.

Comment: So at the end, if I use jarsigner, no action required to take or do I have to switch apksigner?

Comment: @Sezgin ACER AFAIK Jarsigner is the old v1 signature scheme. The APK Signing Block is the [v2 signature scheme](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2).

Comment: My App is removed from play store by Google, with heading "Security metadata to be added to APKs".Can I upload app again to play store?What is about metadata?Google add it to upload time or not?